# Lists aggregation in python

Tags: python, list

I have been trying for a while now to solve the following problem:
I have a list of lists in the following format:

```
[[u'unicode_text', 5, 395, 2, 0, 2 .. n], 
 [u'unicode_text', 235, 5, 3, 3, 10 .. n], 
 [u'other_unicode_text', 3, 65, 28, 16, 52 .. n],
 ...
 [u'unicode_text', 95, 5, 8, 7, 38 .. n]]
```

I am trying to create a new list which will contain the sums of the numbers grouped by the text elements in the list. The result of the above will look like the following list:

```
[[u'unicode_text', 335, 405, 13, 10, 50 .. n],
 [u'other_unicode_text', 3, 65, 28, 16, 52 .. n]]
```

I have tried many ways but I couldn't get to an elegant solution. Zip will not work for unicode text and itertools groupby works for dictionaries.

Comment: `itertools.groupby` works for any iterable.

Comment: OrderedDict works but it gives me a list of grouped lists. Is there an other way (not like ['txt', [2,3]] but ['txt', 2, 3]). I may missing something out there. Thanks

Comment: You can get that using: `['txt'] + [2, 3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the data is `keyed` by the first item in each sublist a dictionary is a better container for the output, you could do something like:

```
import operator

output = dict()
container =  [[u'unicode_text', 5, 395, 2, 0, 2],
              [u'unicode_text', 235, 5, 3, 3, 10],
              [u'other_unicode_text', 3, 65, 28, 16, 52],
              [u'unicode_text', 95, 5, 8, 7, 38]]

for sublist in container:
    try:
        output[sublist[0]] = map(operator.add, output[sublist[0]], sublist[1:])
    except KeyError:
        output[sublist[0]] = sublist[1:]
```

This is a quite simple approach, if it's the first time we see a key then we set just set the value to be the list otherwise we sum each value together and store the new summed list, giving:

```
{ u'other_unicode_text': [3, 65, 28, 16, 52], 
  u'unicode_text':       [335, 405, 13, 10, 50] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `pandas`, this would be easy:

```
In [5]: d=[[u'uicode_text', 5, 395, 2, 0, 2  ], 
   ...:  [u'uicode_text', 235, 5, 3, 3, 10  ], 
   ...:  [u'other_uicode_text', 3, 65, 28, 16, 52  ],
   ...:  [u'uicode_text', 95, 5, 8, 7, 38  ]]

In [6]: import pandas as pd
   ...: df=pd.DataFrame(d)
   ...: print df.groupby(0).sum()
                     1    2   3   4   5
0                                      
other_uicode_text    3   65  28  16  52
uicode_text        335  405  13  10  50
```